# Synchronizing a custom animatable UIView property with other animations

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, calayer, uiviewanimation

I have an `UIView` subclass with a custom animatable property which is animated alongside other (built-in) `UIView` properties on other views. The issue I'm having is related to the fact that this custom property seems to be slightly out-of-sync with the rest of the layout during an animation.

Here's a simple example to illustrate what I mean:

[image: Custom property synchronization issue]

The blue square is animated using the built-in `transform` property, whereas the red square is being drawn inside another (stationary) `UIView` and animated by a custom property `drawFrame`. The animation of both properties match so that, in theory, both rectangles should be perfectly aligned vertically with each other at all times.

Below is the code for the example above. To execute, simply start a new Single View App project and replace the contents of `ViewController.swift`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let viewA = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
    let viewB = CustomAnimatedPropertyView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 150, width: 200, height: 100))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(viewA); viewA.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view.addSubview(viewB); viewB.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        animate()
    }

    func animate() {
        viewA.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        viewB.drawFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 1.0, options: [], animations: {
            self.viewA.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 0.0)
            self.viewB.drawFrame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        })
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 3) { self.animate() }
    }
}

class CustomAnimatedPropertyView: UIView {

    @objc dynamic var drawFrame: CGRect = CGRect.zero {
        didSet {
            guard let layer = layer as? CustomAnimatedPropertyLayer else { fatalError() }
            layer.drawFrame = drawFrame
        }
    }

    override public class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CustomAnimatedPropertyLayer.self
    }

    override public func action(for layer: CALayer, forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
        if event == #keyPath(CustomAnimatedPropertyLayer.drawFrame),
           let action = super.action(for: layer, forKey: #keyPath(backgroundColor)) as? CAAnimation,
           let animation: CABasicAnimation = (action.copy() as? CABasicAnimation) {
            animation.keyPath = #keyPath(CustomAnimatedPropertyLayer.drawFrame)
            animation.fromValue = (layer as! CustomAnimatedPropertyLayer).drawFrame
            animation.toValue = drawFrame
            layer.add(animation, forKey: #keyPath(CustomAnimatedPropertyLayer.drawFrame))
            return animation
        }
        return super.action(for: layer, forKey: event)
    }

    override func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in ctx: CGContext) {
        guard let customLayer = layer as? CustomAnimatedPropertyLayer else { super.draw(layer, in: ctx); return }
        ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        ctx.fill(customLayer.drawFrame)
        usleep(20 * 1000) // <- To exacerbate the synchronization issue
    }
}

class CustomAnimatedPropertyLayer: CALayer {

    @NSManaged var drawFrame: CGRect
    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        return super.needsDisplay(forKey: key) || key == #keyPath(drawFrame)
    }
}
```

I've tried *a lot* of different solutions to no avail... I think this could be solved using a `CADisplayLink` or similar, but I'd prefer to avoid solutions that involve significant code refactoring.

Any idea on how to solve this? Thank you in advance for any answers.

Comment: put code in viewDidAppear

Comment: @Sh_Khan Same result. I should also point out that the sample code above is a very simplified version of the actual production code I'm working on.

Comment: both view have not the same X position

Comment: @Sh_Khan I'm not sure why you say that... The blue view is a perfect 100x100px square which is translated to the right 100px. The red view is as 200x100px rectangle which does not move at all - only the rectangle being drawn inside it gets updated, exactly 100px to the right from its initial position. The origin X coordinate for both views is the same.

Comment: I think drawFrame causes a delay of the draw process + the animation but viewA animation only

Comment: why `viewB.drawFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)` in animate? In that moment the x position is not the same.

Comment: @Kevinosaurio `drawFrame`'s values are expressed in the target `UIView`'s coordinate system. Point `(0, 0)` matches the top left corner of the red square view.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no general solution for your problem, and the jerking of the animations come from there different types. A transformation animation should be more complex than a simple animation on scalar value.

However, I see the following possibilities to get rid of the snchronzation problem. I have several alternative suggestions for you.

1. If your two animations are *really* translations, you should both express as translations:

   1. The probably best way should be put both layers into a common super layer and move the super layer.
   2. Or use the same animation property for both animations, e.g. translate by their `transformation` property. You should use a common basic animation for both layers.
2. If a custom animatable property for one animation is really needed, you should try to express the other animation by a custom property too. If both animations are based on different custom properties you may use an animation group which should improve the synchronization of both animations. (Note: If an animation is based on a common property, you can't use a group, because it will also animate the common property on the other layer.)
3. If both animated values are strictly connected you may create a combined layer which displays the content of both layers. It has just one animatable property which changes its representation appropriately.

Unfortunately, my proposals are, admittedly, very general, but in order to be able to give a more specific path, I would have to know more about the specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! To be more specific, I'm trying to add animations to a tool for cropping images within a specialized image editor app. It looks roughly like same crop/transform tool found in iOS's default Photos app. The image in background is being animated using UIKit's `center` and `transform` properties while the crop mask is being drawn on top of it using a custom animatable property `cropArea`. Their respective layers are on different levels of the layout hierarchy. So I think this means suggestions 1) and 3) do not apply. I'm going to try suggestion 2) to see if it works.

Comment: @DPR: Since you can also draw a scaled image, you should keep option 3 in mind as a reserve.